# Alertmanager does not load webhook_config

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-alertmanager, opsgenie

I want to create new receiver and route for alertmanager to send heartbeats to OpsGenie.

I tried to achieve it by defining opsgenie_config but I wasn't able to send the pings to heartbeats in OpsGenie (I am able to send alerts to OpsGenie with same api key).

Another method I found was to use webhook_config (as suggested in [#444](https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/pull/444#issuecomment-492550235)) and my manifest looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  name: opsgenie-webhook
  labels:
    managedBy: team-sre
spec:
  receivers:
  - name: heartbeat
    webhookConfigs:
    - httpConfig:
        basicAuth:
          password:
            name: opsgenie-api-key
            key: address
      url: https://api.opsgenie.com/v2/heartbeats/sre-test-cluster/ping
  route:
    groupWait: 0s
    repeatInterval: 1m
    groupInterval: 1m
    matchers:
    - name: alertname
      value: Watchdog
    receiver: heartbeat
```

When I apply the manifest the described receiver and route are not loaded to the Alertmanager. When I check the logs there is no error recorded but also no message stating that the sidecar tried to load the new alertmanagerconfig.

Did anyone experience same problem and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on [github issue #3970](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/3970#issuecomment-888893008)
For basicAuth to be accepted, both username and password must be provided.
Nice hack for it is to set username as : in base64 format (Og==).
The manifests should be defined as follows:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    managedBy: team-sre
  name: alertmanager-opsgenie-config
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  receivers:
  - name: deadmansswitch
    webhookConfigs:
      # url link to the specific heartbeat, replace test with heartbeat name
      - url: 'https://api.opsgenie.com/v2/heartbeats/<hearbeat-name>/ping'
        sendResolved: true
        httpConfig:
          basicAuth:
            # reference to secret containing login credentals
            password:
              key: apiKey
              name: opsgenie
            username:
              key: username
              name: opsgenie
  route:
    groupBy:
    - job
    groupInterval: 10s
    groupWait: 0s
    repeatInterval: 10s
    matchers:
      - name: alertname
        value: Watchdog
      - name: namespace
        value: monitoring
    receiver: deadmansswitch

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: monitoring
  name: opsgenie
type: Opaque
data:
  # apiKey in encoded in base64
  apiKey: YOUR_PASSWORD
  # ':' in base 64 - fix suggested in https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/3970#issuecomment-888893008
  username: Og==
```

After the manifest are applied and the alert definition matching the criteria is firing, Opsgenie is hit with heartbeat.